# passing an IIFE to a function that takes a callback as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, iife

I am in the process of removing jQuery from a browser extension and I wrote a simple method (that should work across browsers) to check if the DOM has loaded. Here is the method:

```
domReady: function(fn) {
    if(document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete'){
        if(fn && typeof fn === 'function'){
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
            if(fn && typeof fn === 'function'){
                fn();
            }
        });             
    }
}
```

This works fine with simple functions, for example `domReady(pageLoad)`. I am wondering if it is possible to pass an IIFE to this the domReady method, however. I have a jQuery code block:

```
$(function(a){
    return function(){
        _Tools.drawBar(a);
    }
}(action));
```

I am not completely sure why this is both wrapped in jQuery and immediately invoked but my guess is that it is to have this code execute when the DOM loads and to keep this function private. I am wondering if it is legal to pass this function into the domReady method, like so:

```
domReady(function(a){
    return function(){                                                  
        _Tools.drawBar(a);
    }
}(action));
```

When I try something similar in the chrome dev console, I get a syntax error saying that the function passed to the domReady method is not a function, however the function does still execute. Is there a good way to alter the domReady method to accomodate an IIFE? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're not passing an IIFE, you're passing whatever value the IIFE returns. So as long as the IIFE returns a function (which it *does*) it should work fine. What do you mean by "something similar" in your console test?

Comment: @Jacques `return function() { ... }` means it returns a function.

Comment: an IIFE is not a type of value in js (just a code pattern), so you can't pass it as a parameter, what you're passing is the return value of function, which turns out be a function too.
I don't see any error in the code you shared, can you include the exact error when you say " I get a syntax error saying that"?.

Comment: Are you checking in a content script or internal files? If internal, you could just use the [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) script attribute. Otherwise, you can use a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of a callback.